# Run Powershell command from cmd with parameters

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I intend to run the following command from a cmd shell

```
git clone $(Get-Clipboard)
```

From the context menu in Explorer.

How would I run such from a command shell? What doesnn't work is

```
PowerShell -Command "git clone $(Get-Clipboard)"
```

It gives `fatal: Too many arguments.`

How would I escape proper the Get-Clipboard command?

Comment: It works for me. What unexpected result/error are you experiencing?

Comment: Please post all terminal output from the command

Comment: @garbb Weird, it now works for me as well. Not sure what I was doing but this seems to be the way after all.

Comment: Next thing how to preserve the working directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Literal Script Block

Using a [literal script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) will allow you to run a PowerShell command from cmd.exe:

```
powershell -command "& {git clone $(Get-Clipboard)} %*"
```

### Registry example

To run this from a directory right click add this to the Windows Registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git-clone]
@="Clone here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\git-clone\command]
@="Powershell -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -Command "Set-Location -LiteralPath '%V' ; git clone $(Get-Clipboard)")\""
```

The command line parameter `-WindowStyle Hidden` [prevents the command window to become visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh?view=powershell-7.3#-noprofile---nop). The `-NoProfile` option [prevents the PowerShell profiles from loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh?view=powershell-7.3#-noprofile---nop) speeding up the process.

(thanks to sionta)

Answer (score 1):

I quoted from the official website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1) which is more or less written like this:

In cmd.exe, there is no such thing as a script block (or ScriptBlock type), so the value passed to Command will always be a string. You can write a script block inside the string, but instead of being executed it will behave exactly as though you typed it at a typical PowerShell prompt, printing the contents of the script block back out to you.

A string passed to Command is still executed as PowerShell code, so the script block curly braces are often not required in the first place when running from cmd.exe. To execute an inline script block defined inside a string, the call operator & can be used:

```
powershell -command "& {git clone $(Get-Clipboard)} %*"
```

Comment: @Toto After the edit there is enough explenation imho