# Context menu to show streaming files

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

In Powershell I use `type -wait` to watch log files updating.

I would like a context menu item that will open a powershell window and `type -wait` the target file. But I can't get it to work.

I've tried various permutations of the command in my .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\WatchFIle]
"MUIVerb"="&Watch File"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\WatchFIle\command]
@="powershell.exe -Command {type -wait \"%V\"}"
```

But all that happens is that a Powershell window briefly appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the window stay open if you add `-NoExit` before `-Command`?

Comment: It does. But the window only shows my command then a new prompt straight after. It's like the command isn't being run or is being run in the background somewhere

Comment: I don't use powershell really, but I think script blocks `{ }` only work from a powershell window. The documentation is not very clear on a quick glance. see for example: https://superuser.com/questions/1804902/run-powershell-command-from-cmd-with-parameters

Comment: Yes! Works without the brackets. Great spot, thanks a lot. Chuck it in an answer if you want the points.

Comment: you can answer and accept since you know the proper commands

Comment: @Yorik: He meant `@="powershell.exe -Command type -wait \"%V\""`